# MYSQL Tuple in IN CLause with wildcard matching

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following problem. suppose I have a table containing an inventory of cars:

```
VIN, MAKE, MODEL, PRICE
```

AND I have another table containing various car classes( eg, compact, mid-sized, suv, etc)

```
MAKE, MODEL, CLASS
JEEP, NULL , SUV
FORD, EXPLORER, SUV
TOYOTA, YARIS, COMPACT
NULL, CUBE, COMPACT
...
```

I am wondering how can I select all cars in the database of a certain class? Perhaps, I want to know how many cars of each class exists?

I can write a query like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CARS WHERE (MAKE, MODEL) IN (SELECT MAKE, MODEL FROM CLASSES WHERE CLASS = 'SUV')
```

The problem here, I wont actually be able to deal with NULLs in my data. I want to say that all models of JEEP are SUVs, or any MAKE car that's called CUBE would be a compact car.

Could this be done assuming there are no conflicts? Can I have a priority set up, like All Porches are CARS except the Cayenne which is an SUV by doing something like this:

```
MAKE, MODEL, CLASS
PORCHE, NULL , CAR
PORCHE, CAYENNE, SUV
```

If this isn't possible with MySQL, is there a better DB technology out there that would be good at this. Lets assume that The CLASSES Table would Contain 50K+ Rows and The CARS Table would contain 5M+ Rows. I am looking for a fast way of performing such a query in the database, and not needing to fetch millions of rows to process in a script? Also What if its not just Make and Model, but also sub-model, engine, etc..

Also, I simplified the data quite a bit, there are 4 levels of hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that make and model cannot be both `null` for a given class. You can use the `ifnull()` function in MySQL:

```
select cl.class, count(*)
from cars c inner join class cl
   on c.make = ifnull(cl.make,c.make)
   and c.model=ifnull(cl.model,c.model)
group by cl.class
```

You may want to add an index on columns `makes` and `model` for faster access. Since `classes` have fewer rows using an inner join (as above) will restrict the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CARS c join
     classes cl
     on (c.make = cl.make or cl.make is null) and
        (c.model = cl.model or cl.model is null) and
        cl.class = 'SUV'
```

The problem is that you might get duplicates.  So the better count starts with:

```
select count(distinct c.vin)
. . .
```

This should work for the two cases you gave, for JEEP and CUBE.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT s.class, COUNT(*)
FROM car c, car_class s
WHERE c.make = s.make 
AND c.model = s.model
GROUP BY s.class

should give you something like

SUV  14
COMPACT 32
TRUCK 11
etc.